# Ionic 2 import looks for js instead of ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am new to `ionic2` and following a tutorial on youtube.

I have created a service in my `src/app/services/` called `RedditService` and it's file name is `reddit.service.ts`

And in `app.component.ts` file I am importing it like this:

```
import { RedditService } from './services/reddit.service';
```

When it builds I get an error:

> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/mubashar/code/js/ionic/ionreddit/src/app/services/reddit.service.js'

it is looks for `reddit.service.js` when it SHOULD BE looking for `reddit.service.ts` and that I think is the problem.

This is the tutorial I am following:

https://youtu.be/ilM8YorL_jI

Comment: If you stop the cli, and then run again `ionic serve`, does the error still persist?

Comment: okay.. i restarted and now i am getting `Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http! Error: No provider for Http! at injectionError `

Comment: I've added an answer regarding that error. Please keep in mind that sometimes when adding new files (services, or pages) the cli may throw an error, but if you stop it and run `ionic serve` you will see the real cause of that error :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep in mind that sometimes when adding new files (services or pages) the CLI may throw an error, but if you stop it and run `ionic serve` again you will see the real cause of that error.

**UPDATE:**

> I restarted and now I am getting Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   No provider for Http! Error: No provider for Http! at injectionError

Providers have Http included by default, and in order to use Http in your app you will need to add the HttpModule to your app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; 

...   

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()   ], 
...
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include the solution `restart cli` so I can accept it. it will help people having same problem in the future.

Comment: Yes, I was just adding that lol. Glad to hear that it worked :)